# Iterating over a model's attributes in EmberJS handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

Is there a way to iterate over a view's context's attributes in EmberJS? I am using Ember-Data (https://github.com/emberjs/data) for ORM.

Lets say I use connectOutlets to register a UserView with a user that has attributes such as email, name, etc. In the connected Handlebars template, is there anyway that I can iterate over those attributes?

I basically need to build a generic view that can be reused with different models...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ryan is right about the attributes, but it takes some doing to actually get where you're going.  My examples here are using the latest RC1 Ember.

Here is an editor template that is model agnostic:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="edit_monster">
    {{#if clientId}}
    <h1>Edit Monster: {{name}}</h1>
    <div>
        {{#each metadata}}
            <span class="edit-label">{{name}}</span>
            <span class="edit-field">
                {{view App.AutoTextField typeBinding="type" nameBinding="name" }}
            </span>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{else}}
    No monster selected.
    {{/if}}  
</script>
```

To make that work, we need a couple of pieces of magic-magic.  This controller is a good start:

```
App.EditMonsterController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    metadata: function() {
        var vals = [];
        var attributeMap = this.get('content.constructor.attributes');
        attributeMap.forEach(function(name, value) {
             vals.push(value);   
        });
        return vals;
    }.property('content')

});
```

That uses that "attributes" property that Ryan mentioned to provide the metadata that we are feeding into our #each up there in the template!

Now, here is a view that we can use to provide the text input.  There's an outer container view that is needed to feed the valueBinding in to the actual textfield.

```
App.AutoTextField = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    type: null,
    name: null,

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.createChildView();
    },
    createChildView: function() {
         this.set('currentView', Ember.TextField.create({
                    valueBinding: 'controller.' + this.get('name'),
                    type: this.get('type')
                }));   
    }.observes('name', 'type')
});
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the whole crazy thing: http://jsfiddle.net/Malkyne/m4bu6/

Comment: The Ember-data link for that fiddle is now 404... Heres an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/ianpetzer/QTdb8/

Comment: The links went off again, i've recreated it now in Codepen here: http://codepen.io/kensnyder/pen/doeEu. No errors but it's not working. I'd love to see this in operation as I need to do precisely this on a side project i'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

The Ember Data objects that represent your models have an `attributes` property that contains all of the attributes for the given model. This is what Ember Data's `toJSON` uses to convert your models into Javascript objects.

You can use this attributes property to read a models attributes and then pull those specific attributes out of an instance. Here is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/BdUyU/1/

Just to reiterate what's going on here. We are reading the attributes from App.User and then pulling the values out of App.ryan and App.steve. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Doing it like this are the values still bound? If these attributes were to change elsewhere would those changes be instantly reflected in this view...or if I were to use form inputs in this view would the form elements be bound to the value of the attribute and vice versa?