# Accessing Values for Key in Handlebars & Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to access properties in a value-for-key style in Handlebars?

I have a CollectionView which uses an ArrayController full of models. The CollectionView has a property called 'columns' that define table column configurations for rendering.

Ideally I'd be able to loop through each column (see example below) ensuring that only the columns we want rendered are rendered (and later, formatting and other attributes are applied)

```
<tr>
  {{#each column in view.controller.columns}}
    <td>
      {{ view.content.[column.name] }}
    </td>
  {{/each}}
</tr>
```

This doesn't work, it just returns no content.

I've also tried these other styles to see if they'd work:

```
<tr>
  {{#each column in view.controller.columns}}
    <td>
      {{ view.content.name }}
      {{ view.content.[column.name] }}
      {{valForKey view.content column.name }}
    </td>
  {{/each}}
</tr>
```

The `valForKey` helper is one I wrote ([source here](https://gist.github.com/d2kagw/5827003)), which *does* display the correct value but doesn't bind, so the value isn't updated when the property changes.

What's the best way to handle this use case in Ember?

Thanks

Comment: This should point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/a/15053152/1369763

Answer (score 1):

Right now Ember has *get* helper included:

```
{{get object key}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bound helper to display the value of the column

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('dd', function(rowData, col) {
  return rowData[col];
});
```

See the following SO answer for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27477602/908842