# Is it possible to use one generic template for several different underlying models in Handlebars.js with Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I defined several (10+) different models in Ember and set up the resource routes. Everythings works fine. Although every model has different attributes I want to save me time writing redundant code. 
Let's start with the models first. Here are some examples...

*Model:* **Client**

```
App.Client = DS.Model.extend({               
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    clientId: DS.attr('string'),
    clientSecret: DS.attr('string'),
    trustedClient: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

*Model:* **Group**

```
App.Group = DS.Model.extend({               
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    groupType: DS.attr('string')
});
```

*Model:* **User**

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({               
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

***and more...***

## Question:

Is it possible to use **one** (*instead of 10+*) handlebars template to generate labels and textfields for every attribute and value combination?

### Idea

I got some ideas from [this question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415299/iterating-over-a-models-attributes-in-emberjs-handlebars-template). It already seems quite useful to define a general template as proposed.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="general-table-output">
    {{#each metadata}}
        <label>{{name}}</label>
        {{input valueBinding='name'}}        
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

And then we can use the render helper to pass a model to the controller of general-table-output. Here an example for **User**.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
    {{render 'general-table-output' user}}
</script>
```

Up until here everything seems fine... But the controller does not seem to find the model's attributes.

### Controller

```
App.GeneralTableOutput = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    metadata: function() {
        var vals = [];
        var attributeMap = this.get('content.constructor.attributes');
        attributeMap.forEach(function(name, value) {
            vals.push(value);   
        });
        return vals;
    }.property('content')
});
```

## Problem

```
attributeMap: undefined
```

### Do you know a way to access an assigned model in the controller and map out all the attributes / values, so that it can be viewed in a generic template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getting the attributes is a little tricky when working with Ember Data.  This is due to Ember Data overriding the default implementation of `Ember.get` so when you call `get` on an Ember Data object it skips its internal properties etc going for the model properties (dirty or committed). You'd need to do `Ember.get(this.get('content'), 'constructor.attributes')`.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/394/edit

Comment: `var constructor = model.get('firstObject.constructor');`
`var a = Em.get(constructor, 'attributes');`

this works fine but it still feels like working against ember.

Comment: Making a generic item like this leads to having to use the innards of Ember, generally I avoid it because then you tend to lose some of the built in functionality, but it all depends on what you're trying to build.

Comment: yes... had the same impression.  I will try to break things into components and partials. Thanks for your advice.