# Ember.js: TextField with dynamic binding

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I want to bind a TextField to a property which is specified by a string variable (see the edit for a better explanation), as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415299/iterating-over-a-models-attributes-in-emberjs-handlebars-template). Unfortunately the answer that was given there does not work anymore. They use the following view there:

```js
App.AutoTextField = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    type: null,
    name: null,

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.createChildView();
    },
    createChildView: function() {
         this.set('currentView', Ember.TextField.create({
                    valueBinding: 'controller.' + this.get('name'),
                    type: this.get('type')
                }));   
    }.observes('name', 'type')
});
```

The best I could get until now was replacing the `valueBinding` with the path `_parentView.context.`. If I do this the text fields get rendered and they contain the correct value. If I edit them the rest of the application doesn't get updated though.

How would you solve this in the current version of Ember?

**Edit:**
A better explanation of what I want to do is given in the linked question. I have an object (say `object`) and a string (`key`) in the current context. I want a text field that can show and render the value of `object[key]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many failed attempts I found a pretty simple solution.

Add the helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('dataTextField', function (data, key, options) {
    options.hash.valueBinding = 'data.' + key;

    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.input.apply(this, [options]);
});
```

and then call

```
{{dataTextField data key}}
```

This will render a text field that shows and changes the value of `data[key]` and it even supports all the optional arguments the normal `input` helper can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind input values with dynamic keys(variables) of objects with help of mut helper now.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_binding-dynamic-attribute

We can bind key in input helper like this,

```
{{input value=(mut (get Object key))}}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a little unclear what your use case is from your question but assuming your just trying to get a basic binding on the text field working then the easiest way to bind a value is to use the input helper:

In your template you would use:

```
{{input type="text" value=inputTextValue}}
```

where `inputTextValue` is the property you are binding the value to.  Then in your controller you could access the `inputTextValue` property to either get the value typed in by the user, or to set the value displayed to the user.

Here's a working fiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/940/

You can find more information on the input helper in the Ember docs here:

> http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_input

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that isn't what I wanted to do. My problem is the same as in the linked question. I have an object (say `object`) in the current context and a string (say `property`). I want to get a text field which can show and change the value of `object[property]`. I found a solution for this today and will show it in an answer.