# Dynamic bound property for an HTMLBars Helper in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars

I have a list of attribute names `attrs` that I would like to iterate over, creating an input with a binding to that attribute on the model for each for each. The below expresses the functionality I'm after:

```
{{#each attr in attrs}}
  {{input value=model.get(attr) }}
{{/each}}
```

Of course this does not actually work, because you can't make method calls in a helper. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308702/ember-js-textfield-with-dynamic-binding), but the solution doesn't work in my version of Ember (1.11.0)-- I gather because `this` is undefined in a helper definition as of version 1.11.0 (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10692)).

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just get a property from the model, named by the current value of your each loop, you could write a helper like:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('input-helper',
    function(model, attr) {
        return Ember.get(model, attr);
    }
);
```

And then use it like:

```
{{#each attr in attrs}}
    {{input-helper model attr}} 
{{/each}}
```

This will print property named to whatever `attr` holds in that `#each` iteration from the `model`

If you want to bound that value to an input, instead of making a helper, you could make a component or a view that will do this for you:

```
// component that binds 'object.property' to an input field
var InputBinderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  prop: null, // passed in
  obj: null,   // passed in
  value: null,    // local

  onValue: function() {
    var obj = this.get('obj');
    var prop = this.get('prop');
    var value = this.get('value');
    Ember.set(obj, prop, value);
  }.observes('value'),
});
```

With `input-binder` component's template to actually contain the input:

```
{{input type="text" value=value}}
```

And then use it in the template:

```
{{#each attr in attrs}}
      {{input-binder prop=attr obj=model}}
{{/each}}
```

### **Here is an Example**

Comment: Thanks, I see that your binding example will work. I wonder whether there are any performance implications though? I don't know very much about how Ember handles things under the hood, but this solution seems to "manually" bind the values rather than using Ember's built-in binding functionality. But maybe it doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: Well, considering that Ember doesn't provide this functionality directly, you kind of have to add an additional layer of observing and getting/setting of values. This is necessary since we have to adjust to the way Ember handles bindings right now which is that variable names on which we are binding have to be known in advance and cannot be dynamically determined (except in manners I showed above). But the performance hit is non-significant since the whole framework is built on making 2-way bindings as efficient as possible (at least to my knowledge)