# Using Ember.js, how do I get a template to show dynamically all of the properties of a model?

Tags: ember.js, model

How do I get a Handelbars template to loop through a model's properties and print them all on the screen?

Here's my router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  // Add your routes here
  this.resource('notifications', { path: '/notifications' });
  this.resource('notification', { path: '/notifications/:notification_id' });
});
```

The dynamic segment is working and I can retrieve a particular model by going to `/notification/0`, for example.

In my notification.hbs, I can do `{{model.status}}` and it properly displays that property from my model, which is a string that equals "CLOSED".  However, my app is going to contain many different models which need to be printed out entirely, and I was trying to figure out a way to loop through the entire model dynamically.  I would like to put something like this in my template:

```
{{#each property in model}}
  <li>{{property.key}}: {{property.value}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

. . . Which would output this:

> ```
> Date: 2014-09-18
> Status: CLOSED
> Assigned: Yes
> Description: Blah
> ```

A side question, I suppose, is how do I view the current model object in Chrome with Ember tools?  In trying to figure out my main question, I went to the Chrome console to try to get info about the model object, to see what I could get out of it.  I typed `model` in the console and got `ReferenceError: model is not defined`.

Comment: Of course, I found a similar question as soon as I posted this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415299/iterating-over-a-models-attributes-in-emberjs-handlebars-template  :-)  Seeing if that fixes my problem.

Comment: You'll want to be careful about that approach if you're data is changing, it won't do data bindings (meaning adding a property or changing properties wouldn't update the ui). At the same time if the data won't change you're good with this approach